# Repeater unable to display results using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, repeater, asprepeater

Repeater unable to display results using ajax.

Here's the jquery function I am calling:

```
function LoadValue() {
    var i = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Test/repeaterControlTest.aspx/GetValues") %>',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var response = data.d;
            var xml = $(response);
            var listItems = xml.find('Table1');
            var item = "";
            item = '' + listItems.find('SystemName').text() + '';
            $('.repeaterBody tbody').html('');
            $('.repeaterBody tbody').append(item);

            showListBox();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error...');
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert('Failure...');
        }
    });
}
```

Html code:

```
<div class="modal-body repeaterBody">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlScroll" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" BorderColor="#C0C0C0"
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" Width="90%" Style="height: 215px; width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">

                <asp:Repeater ID="rptListBox" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <table style="width: 100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="lblItem" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="Select" Text='<%# Eval("SystemName") %>' Style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" CssClass="btnItem"></asp:Button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

repeater doesn't shows any result. But when I trying to display that response values just as text inside Panel by removing `Reteater` to table then that displays result. What is issue in above code?

Comment: You probably don't have a `tbody` - there's certainly not one in the code you've provided.  Even if there was, the table is inside the repeater but you replace a single tbody, so you'd replace every "row" in your rptListBox

Comment: So how could I bind that response?

Comment: Maybe change your jquery selector, eg from `$('.repeaterBody tbody').append(item);` to `$('.repeaterBody').append(item);` - depends on what you're getting back in the ajax call - the entire repeaterBody or individual rows (unlikely as you're not passing anything into the call)